# A minimum set hitting every base of a matroid

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-complexity, matroid-theory

We are given a matroid. Our goal is to find a set of elements of minimum size that has non-empty intersection with every base of the matroid. Is the problem studied before? Is it in P? For example, in a spanning tree matroid, the minimum hitting set should be a minimum cut. Thanks.

Crossposted at [CSTheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11498/min-hitting-set-of-every-base-of-a-matroid).

Comment: Such a set is also called a vertex cover of the matroid/simplicial complex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is hard in general.  Note that a minimal set that intersects every base of a matroid $M$ is a dependent set in the dual matroid $M^{*}$.  Such sets are called *cocircuits*.  So, you are looking for the shortest cocircuit of a matroid.

The shortest cocircuit problem (equivalently shortest circuit problem) is NP-complete in general (even for binary matroids).  See this Matroid Union [post](http://matroidunion.org/?p=1106) for more information on finding shortest circuits in binary matroids.

Comment: I have an additional question: Is there anything known about the complexity of computing the shorest circuit/cocircuit problem on transversal matroids or Gammoids? Thanks. (BTW: should I make this a Quesion instead of a comment?)

Comment: Hmmm...I'm not sure about transversal matroids or Gammoids, but my guess is that it's still hard.  Probably you should post this as a separate question so that it is more visible to others.  It's also good etiquette to link questions that are posted at multiple sites.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

A set intersects every base of a matroid $M$ iff it includes the complement of some hyperplane.  In more detail: $X$ intersects every base iff $M-X$ includes no base iff $M-X$ fails to span $M$ iff $M-X$ is included in some hyperplane $H$ iff $X$ includes the complement of some hyperplane $H$.