# shortest circuit/cocircuit problem on transversal matroids or Gammoids

Tags: co.combinatorics

Is the shortest circuit/cocircuit problem on transversal matroids or gammoids NP-hard?
Is there anything known about this?
It is known that the shortest circuit on binary matroid is NP-hard. But I can not find 
any reference on transversal matroids or gammoids.

This is a followup question of 
[A minimum set hitting every base of a matroid](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97517/a-minimum-set-hitting-every-base-of-a-matroid)

Answer (score 2):

The shortest circuit problem for Transversal matroids is NP-hard, by a reduction from Clique. See Theorem 2.1 in "Reliable Assignments of Processors to Tasks and Factoring on Matroids" by Charles J. Colbourn and Ehab S. Elmallah ( http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.56.6967 ).